# Nowhere dense set characterization

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subseteq X$ then $A$ is nowhere dense ($int(\overline{A}) = \emptyset$) if and only if $A \subseteq \overline{X-\ \overline{A}}$

I've already done one side, $int(\overline{A})=\emptyset \Leftrightarrow X-\overline{(X-\overline{A})} = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow \overline{X-\overline{A}} = X \Rightarrow A \subseteq X = \overline{X-\overline{A}}$

Comment: If you are not convinced by the answer posted below, try interacting with the answerer to get your doubts cleared. If you are satisfied, consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick mark button next to the answer. Doing so will award reputation points both to you and the answerer for taking the time out to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the other direction, for convenience let $U=\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}A$. $U\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$, so $U\cap X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A=\varnothing$, and therefore $U\cap\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A)=\varnothing$, since $U$ is open. If $U\ne\varnothing$, let $x\in U$. Then $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$, and $U$ is an open nbhd of $x$, so $U\cap A\ne\varnothing$. Let $y\in U\cap A$; then $y\in A\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A)$, so $A\nsubseteq\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A)$.